# ServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding return error in the domino 9.0.1 servlets

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, lotus-domino

I want to upload a file contain the non-ascii character with HTML file widget, the backend is using the servlet in the domino 9.0.1 to accept the file content, 
I invoke the `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");` in the `doService` method within my servlet, but I got the following error in the domino log file

> HTTP JVM: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ?javax/servlet/ServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(Ljava/lang/String;)V: javax/servlet/ServletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(Ljava/lang/String;)V

Just wonder if anyone got the similar issue and how to resolve it. Anyone knew what the web module version(servlet version) was supported in the domino 9.0.1.
The code can be compiled in Java IDE, but the deployed code servlet into the domino server will throw that error. Just wonder how to resolve it, thanks.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Seems like the `ServletRequest` is being used instead of the `HttpServletRequest`.